# Require a custom LWRP

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

I am stuck trying to create my first lwrp

I have created a very basic resource + provider at:

```
resources/rack_site.rb
providers/rack_site.rb
```

I've been trying to test the 'rack_site' resource within a recipe of the same cookbook, but it fails with an error about resource not found. I tried moving both files into a cookbook which I added as dependency, but still fails.

What must be done to use a custom resource into a recipe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This got me too.  You can access the LWRP by prepending the cookbook name from your `metadata.rb` and an underscore to the resource name.  For example if the rack site resource is in the Foo cookbook: `foo_rack_site`.

Answer (score 8):

Chef uses the name of the cookbook (as defined in the `metadata.rb`) to prefix LWRPs. For example, if your cookbook was named `acme-nginx`, and you have a resource named `rack_site.rb`, the associated LWRP in the recipe DSL is `acme_nginx_rack_site`. For example:

```rb
acme_nginx_rack_site 'foo' do
  # ...
end
```

Chef will automatically convert characters which are not valid for Ruby methods to an underscore (including dashes).

Comment: For cases where you don't want your LWRP to be prefixed with the cookbook name (as is the convention for a most 'heavy weight' resources) you can use the `provides` method to specify the shorter name.  Adding `provides :rack_site` to the top of both the resource and provider files would do the trick in the above case.